# How to FadeIn an Appended Div without Fading In All Divs displayed?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors

Ok. I know this is probably pretty simple, but I am having a difficult time with it :/.

**I am trying to make Divs FadeIn when they are appended to a parent div. My problem is, that when new divs are appended, all of them fade in.:**

```
<div id="click">Click Me</div>
<div id="textResp"></div>


$('#click').live('click',function() {
$('#textResp').append("<div id='hi' class='eventdiv'>hello</div>").hide().fadeIn(3000);
});
```

**I know that it is because the fadeIn(3000) is attached to the parent because it is starting with $('#textResp'), but how do you attach this to the created object?**

Thanks,

Taylor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply create your element via a jQuery and call the `hide()` and `fadeIn()` methods on that object and not `#textResp`

```
$('#click').live('click', function() {
    var $d = $("<div id='hi' class='eventdiv'>hello</div>").hide().fadeIn(3000);
    $('#textResp').append($d)
});
```

**[Example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/Cx7wX/)**

*Side note*, I am sure this is just a generalized example, but the id should be unique.

```
$('#click').live('click', function() {
    var $d = $("<div/>", {
        id: 'hi' + $('#textResp').children().length, //generate a unique id
        class: 'eventdiv',
        html: 'hello'
    }).hide().fadeIn(3000);

    $('#textResp').append($d);
});
```

**[Example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/Cx7wX/1/)**

Comment: How could you fade the div in prior to it being appended to an element that's already attached to the dom? The call to fadeIn can't happen until the element is appended.

Comment: `fadeIn()` will still run on the jQuery object regardless if it is appended to the dom.  See http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/Cx7wX/2/ as the opacity changes while not being attached to the dom.

Comment: That may work but I'd still say you're taking advantage of an unintuitive quirk. I just tried my code and it works as well. I think it more logically expresses the intent but so be it.

Answer (score 0):

Try reversing the order of your chain. I'd do it like this...

```
$("<div id='hi' class='eventdiv'>hello</div>").appendTo("#textResp").hide().fadeIn(3000);
```

That way, when you "fadeIn", you're still in the context of the newly created div.
Based on your question, I'm assuming this is the desired behavior. It's a lot more straightforward than the other 2 answers I've observed.

Comment: That will attach it to the #click div. Without hide() it will not fadeIn

Comment: And no two elements can have the same id. ;)

Comment: @Rob I'd definitely agree. He should be using the class attribute if nothing else. Like <div class="newly-appended"> or something.

Answer (score 0):

Two problems:

First, all your appended divs have the same id, 'hi'. As separate elements they need distinct ids.

Second, you're using fadeIn(3000) on $('#textResp'), not the appended div. Try something like this:

```
$('#textResp').append("<div class='eventdiv'>hello</div>");
$('#textResp div:last-child').hide().fadeIn(3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var count=1;
    $('#click').live('click',function() {
        var id='hi'+count,
            elt=$('<div id="'+id+'" class="eventdiv">hello</div>');
        $('#textResp').append(elt.hide().fadeIn(3000));
        count++;
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hide it from the beginning and then just show the last one

```
$('#click').live('click',function() {
    $('#textResp').append("<div style='display: none' class='eventdiv'>hello </div>");
    $('#textResp div:last-child').fadeIn(1000);
});
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/xp6fU/